# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception in Java in case of Insertion Sort

Tags: java, insertion-sort

```
class Insertionsort
{

int A[] = {5,2,4,6,1,3};

void insertionSort()
{

    for(int j=2;j<A.length;j++)
    {
    int key = A[j];
    int i = j-1;
        while(i>0 && A[i]>key)
        {
            A[i+1]=A[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
        A[i+1]=key;
    }

    for(int j = 0;j<=A.length;j++)
    {
    System.out.println(A[j]);
    }


}

public static void main(String args[])
{

Insertionsort is = new Insertionsort();

is.insertionSort();

}

}
```

---

Problem is:

The Output of this is 5 1 2 3 4 6 instead of 1 2 3 4 5 6.

What to do?

Comment: Try debugger. It helps.

Comment: Problem in array access `0` is legal array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is causing the error:

```
for(int j = 0;j<=A.length;j++)
    System.out.println(A[j]);
```

Max index of an array is `length - 1` so change it to:

```
for(int j = 0;j<A.length;j++)
    System.out.println(A[j]);
```

Better yet, why not use the enhanced `for`? That way you don't make this kind of mistake:

```
for(int a : A)
    System.out.println(a);
```

**Back to your algorithm:**

Starting from `j=2` you leave out your first element so change it to `j=1`.
Also your inner loop should go until `i>=0` else you also leave out the 0th element (array index is 0-based):

```
for (int j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
    int key = A[j];
    int i = j - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && A[i] > key) {
        A[i + 1] = A[i];
        i = i - 1;
    }
    A[i + 1] = key;
}
```

This will print out `1 2 3 4 5 6` (in new lines since `println()` is used).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort an Array, you just need to use Sort() from Arrays class.

`Arrays.sort(yourArray);`

Comment: This method doesn't use `insertion sort` but as stated in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) `Dual-Pivot Quicksort`. While in real world your answer would be most welcome I am afraid that OPs teacher may not accept your solution.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int j = 0;j<=A.length;j++)`

change to `j<A.length` to make your OutOfBounds Exception go away.

also, your other loops have wrong start/end conditions

`for(int j=2;j<A.length;j++)` should start at `j=1` and `while(i>0 && A[i]>key)` should have `i>=0` or the first element in the array will be skipped in your sort (the 5).

Answer (score 0):

In your sorting loop you initialize `j = 2` and then get an number from the array with `int key = A[j];` so the first number in the array you try to sort is index 2. Since the first element in an array has the index 0, you are leaving out 5 and 2 when sorting. Change the loop to

```
for(int j = 0; j < A.length(); j++){
    int key = A[j];
    int i = j-1;
    ....
```

Answer (score -1):

class Insertionsort
{

int A[] = {5,2,4,6,1,3};

void insertionSort()
{

```
for(int j=1;j<A.length;j++)
{
int key = A[j];
int i = j-1;
    while(i>=0 && A[i]>key)
    {
        A[i+1]=A[i];
        i=i-1;
    }
    A[i+1]=key;
}

for(int j = 0;j<A.length;j++)
{
System.out.print(A[j] + " ");
}
```

}

public static void main(String args[])
{

Insertionsort is = new Insertionsort();

is.insertionSort();

}

}